# How to execute string php code to run

Tags: php

I have got string response is `"<?php  $a=array("10","20");  echo $a[0]+a[1];   ?>"`

How to execute this string.
I use PHP 7.0.

Please give any solution.

Comment: Why is this tagged with json, laravel, codeigniter and yii? Looks like tag-spamming.

Comment: You can use `eval()` but is rare and dangerous it use, why tou got this response string ?

Comment: corrected `echo $a[0]+$a[1];`

Comment: You could use http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php and open yourself to a variety of security problems. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php/951868.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does the string come from and why do you need to execute it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already stated you can use [`eval($string);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). Beware that `eval()` evaluates a string as PHP code, so you need to be careful with the strings you allow to be passed!

If you take the string yourself from a predefined set of strings you created (using a `swtich` statement or something similar) it shouldn't be a problem.

If the string comes from the outside (user input or cURL requests or whatever) you shouldn't trust it and you should avoid using this method.

Comment: I have using eval('?>'.$string.'<?php;');

Comment: @Renukas, I know it is tooooo late to comment smth here, but mb it will be helpful for someone else. Beware too, because $string could contain "<?php ... ?>", so in your example, you aren't avoiding executing php code